NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances is not supported
So I tried to refactor code to return responses in a cleaner. But I can't seem to wrap my head around why when I try to put the errorResponse in the ResponseBody it returns not supported exception. Could somebody explain?
public class ResponseBodyBase
{
    public string LogId { get; set; }
    public ErrorResponseBody Error { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseBody : ResponseBodyBase
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ListId { get; set; }
    public string SiteId { get; set; }
    public bool? ToDropOffLocation { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseDebugBody : ResponseBody
{
    public object Variables { get; set; } 
}

public static ResponseBody CreateResponse(HttpRequest req, string logId, DocumentVariables documentVariables, ErrorResponseBody errorResponse)
{
    // Determine if debug information is requested
    bool isDebugMode = req.Headers.TryGetValue("debug", out var debugHeader) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(debugHeader);

    var standardResponse = new ResponseBody
    {
        LogId = logId,
        ItemId = documentVariables.ListItemId,
        ListId = documentVariables.ListId,
        SiteId = documentVariables.SiteId,
        Error = // null works, but if I put anything related to errorResponse here it goes wrong
    };

    // If in debug mode, add additional debug information
    if (isDebugMode)
    {
        return CreateDebugResponse(baseResponse, documentVariables);
    }

    return baseResponse;
}

private static ResponseDebugBody CreateDebugResponse(ResponseBody baseResponse, DocumentVariables documentVariables)
{
    return new ResponseDebugBody
    {
        LogId = baseResponse.LogId,
        ItemId = baseResponse.ItemId,
        ListId = baseResponse.ListId,
        SiteId = baseResponse.SiteId,
        Variables = new
        {
            // excess variables
        },
        ToDropOffLocation = false
    };
}

And I'm returning the response like this:
 ErrorResponseBody errorResponse = new ErrorResponseBody
 {
     Timestamp = DateUtils.CreateTimeStamp(),
     Status = 422,
     Code = "Can't process entity",
     Message = e.Message,
     LogId = logId,
     InnerError = e
 };

 var response = ResponseBody.CreateResponse(req, logId, documentVariables, errorResponse); // this goes fine

 return new OkObjectResult(response) // returning this throws exception
 {
     StatusCode = errorResponse.Status,
     ContentTypes = { "application/json" }
 };


The error is telling you that you are trying to serialize an object that cannot be serialized. If this only occurs when you set ErrorResponseBody, then the problem is likely in that type, so you should show the type definition. I would also recommend setting up a unit test to serialize/deserialize your types so any problems can be reproduced in a simpler way.

Oh, could it be because InnerError is of type Exception? The rest are just strings and one int.

That would be the first thing I would try at least.

Yup, Exception is apparently not serializable I guess. Thank you o7
